# Tensor product of multiple matrices

Tags: python, sympy

I trying to use sympy TensorProduct to evaluate the tensor product of more than 2 matrices.

The example below works

```
from sympy.physics.quantum import TensorProduct
from sympy import Matrix

m1 = Matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
m2 = Matrix([[1,0],[0,1]])
m3 = Matrix([[1,1],[1,1]])

prod = TensorProduct(m1, m2, m3)
```

My question is if it's possible to do something like:

```
matrices = [m1, m2, m3]
prod = TensorProduct(matrices)
```

I tried define `matrices` as an array and a tuple but doesn't work. Didn't find another function to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to unpack `matrices`, like this:

```py
matrices = [m1, m2, m3]
prod = TensorProduct(*matrices)
prod
```